# Website Home Page With No Toolbar

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a snippet of javascript to use to open a home page without toolbars.

I do not want to open from a link with - `window.open()`

This is for a portfolio that I just want the plain window showing.

I can resize with - `window.resizeTo()`

But I can't find any code to get rid of the titlebar & menubar...

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without using `window.open()`, and that will get killed by a lot of pop-up blockers.